# javascript confirm popup within PHP while loop not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, popup

I have the following code setup to delete records from my database. It executes fine except for the javascript confirm message which never pops up. It just gets ignored completely and the record gets deleted. Any ideas why?

```
 connect_to_db();
    $query="SELECT id, date, title, image FROM content ORDER BY date DESC";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $message= "Continue?";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<div id="delete" align="center">';
    echo '<a href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'" onclick = "if (! confirm('.$message.')) { return false; }" ><img src="'.$row['image'].'" style="border:1px solid black; width:100px;"><br>Delete</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: can you post the anchor html it is outputting?

Comment: looks to me there is going to be conflicts with 'message' `confirm(\''.$message.'\'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a missing quotes issue:

```
echo '<a href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'" onclick = "if (! confirm(\''.$message.'\')) { return false; }" ><img src="'.$row['image'].'" style="border:1px solid black; width:100px;"><br>Delete</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Continue?` message is shown as a bare string in the JavaScript code, which is for obvious reasons invalid.

Try this:

```
'... onclick="return confirm(&quot;'.$message.'&quot;);" ...'
```